# Quartz versioning issue with jboss

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, jboss-4.2.x

I m having quartz 1.7.3 in .grails/plugins folder in development environment

where in grails/web-inf/lib i have quartz-1.8.4.jar version

It works properly in development sts 3.1.0 IDE version

When i moved the same to production environment by creating war directory in the war folder it includes both 1.7.3 and quartz-1.8.4.jar files at .war/web-inf/lib/

where in jboss/server/default/lib contains quartz.jar (i.e. 1.5.2 comes with by default jboss)

now i m facing issue in invoking quartz jobs on start up and afterwards

**same thing is working without changing anything in other server only i m facing the compatibility after putting logs in config.groovy i came to know the error.**

I tried to put one jar from 1.7 or 1.8 in web-inf/lib still didn't worked

I did put the 1.5.2 version in web-inf/lib folder still i m facing compatibility issue

Any idea/suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was versioning issue as more than one jar of diff versions were getting conflicting came to know after switching to logging in the system. As there were one more jar included in jboss-web-deplyer/lib directory after removing that jar the problem got resolved.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember, 
You need to check the quatz tables in the db, may in the other server ther not exist in the db or somting like that..
Tables are starting QURTZ_? 
There is somting like 5-7 tables in the db.

Comment: i cant check it as the job are not getting initiated at all

Comment: Yes, but the jobs are saved in the db.. so create those table and jobs and the add corn trigger and check if it run..